# $2-\frac{2^2}{x+1}+\frac{2^3}{(x+1)^2}-\frac{2^4}{(x+1)^3}+...+\frac{2^r}{[-(x+1)]^{r-1}}+...$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification

A series is given as follows,
$$2-\frac{2^2}{x+1}+\frac{2^3}{(x+1)^2}-\frac{2^4}{(x+1)^3}+...+\frac{2^r}{[-(x+1)]^{r-1}}+...$$

Find the set of values of $x$ such that the series converges. If the series converges to $\frac{9}{5}$, find the value of $x$.

My attempt,
$$2-\frac{2^2}{x+1}+\frac{2^3}{(x+1)^2}-\frac{2^4}{(x+1)^3}+...+\frac{2^r}{[-(x+1)]^{r-1}}+...=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^r}{[-(x+1)]^{r-1}}$$

By using ratio test:
$$L=\lim_{r \to \infty} \bigg|\frac{a_{ \space r+1}}{a_r}\bigg|$$
$$=\lim_{r \to \infty} \bigg|\frac{a_{ \space r+1}}{a_r}\bigg|$$
$$=\bigg|\frac{2}{-(x+1)}\bigg|$$

$$\bigg|\frac{2}{-(x+1)}\bigg|<1$$
$$x<-3 \space \text{or} \space x>1$$

If the series converges to $\frac{9}{5},$$\frac{2}{-(x+1)}=\frac{9}{5}$
$$x=-\frac{19}{9}$$

Am I correct? Or is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: Have you studied already power series? Do you understand that $$|x|<1\implies \frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\,?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my comment, and since your series is:

$$2\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac2{x+1}\right)^n=\stackrel{\text{for}\;\left|\frac2{x+1}\right|<1}=2\frac1{1+\frac2{x+1}}=\frac{2(x+1)}{x+3}$$

You now know for which set of avalues the series converges (your radius evaluation is correct since: $\;\left|\frac2{x+1}\right|<1\iff|x+1|>2\iff x>1\;\;or\;\;x<-3\;$), and it is given that

$$\frac{2(x+1)}{x+3}=\frac95\implies10x+10=9x+27\implies x=17$$

Check carefully the above for any mistakes...

Comment: Long time no see, my friend !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Mon cher ami! Long time no see, indeed. I was in Paris in september but for a short time (and in fact I don't know whether you live in Paris or not). Hopefully next time we could meet.

Comment: I am in Pau. South West, very close to the Spanish border and 60 miles from the Atlantic. Good food, good wine here. Be my guest !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Merci beaucoup. I'd love to travel to that place, which is also close to Biarritz.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't have permission to comment, so I must post this.

Your ratio test is correct, but it seems you have made an arithmetic error following
$$\left | \frac{2}{-(x+1)} \right | < 1$$
It should yield $x<-3$ and $x>1$.

You cannot use the result of the ratio test as the value the series converges to, do you see why this is the case?

Comment: I like ead1's comment, because it is the only one where I clearly see $\frac{-2}{x+1}$ as an entity ; The serie is a geometric serie, with ratio  $\frac{-2}{x+1}$, and we know '''magic ''' formulas for geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

let $z =\frac{1}{x+1} $ the Radius of convergence $R$ of a power series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n z^n $ is defined as $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sup\{|\sqrt[n ] {c_n}| \}}= \frac{1}{2} $ so it converge where $|z|< \frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{1}{|x+1|} < \frac{1}{2}$ the it converge when $|x+1|>2$ and since you are untested in real valued $x$ then we can check the end points $1, -3$ which in both cases diverge

$$\frac{-1}{z}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n 2^n z^n$$
notice that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n -{2z}^{n}$ is a geometric series converge when $z< \frac{1}{2}$ and its sum is $ \frac{2z}{1+2z}$
$$\frac{1}{z} \times \frac{2z}{1+2z } =\frac{2}{1+2z} =\frac{9}{5}  $$
$$z=\frac{1}{18}$$
$$x= 17$$